# How can a dynamically generated JavaFX scene be changed in a single stage?

Tags: javafx, scene

I'm currently working on a project requiring me to switch back and forward between scenes. I have already written some code for it but it isn't as elegant as I wanted to be, especially as there is few flickers when I switch between them and sometimes even the buttons that I have generated simply disappear only to appear once again when yet another scene has been generated. Moreover, the layout I'm using for my application isn't really fixed and I think that using FXML might be not suitable for what I'm doing.

Thank you.

This  is what I'm using to change between scenes:

```
void changeScene(Stage stage,Scene scene){
    stage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How do I switch between scenes , preferably without using FXML's.

Comment: The answer to the question is that you either call `setScene(...)` on the `Stage`, and pass in a new `Scene`, or you call `setRoot(...)` on the existing `Scene`, and pass in the new root of the scene graph. I sort of suspect that doesn't help you though, you need to put a lot more detail into your question if you want a more helpful answer.

Comment: There is too much code there, presumably with a lot of it irrelevant to the actual question you are trying to ask; also it will not compile on its own. It's not really at all clear what you are asking here. Please create (probably from scratch) an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Does that give you a better idea ? This is the method I have created to change between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "switching between scenes" you mean that you want to change the entire content of the existing window.

There are two (very) slightly different ways you can do this. Either create a new `Scene` and pass it to the `Stage`'s `setScene(...)` method. Or create the `Parent` that is the root of the new UI (either by FXML or otherwise), and pass it to the existing `Scene`'s `setRoot(...)` method. There's no real advantage that I can see of one over the other.

Here's a minimal implementation of the second option. The UI is irrelevant to the question: the important parts are the event handlers for the "Login" button (which switches from the login scene to the main scene) and the "Logout" button (which switches back).

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MinimalSceneSwitchingExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LoginView loginView = new LoginView();
        Scene scene = new Scene(loginView.getView(), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class LoginView {

        private final IntegerProperty loginAttempts ;

        private final GridPane view ;

        public LoginView() {

            view = new GridPane();

            TextField usernameTF = new TextField("user");
            TextField passwordTF = new TextField("pass");

            // Login button switches to main view:
            Button loginButton = new Button("Login");
            loginButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                if (usernameTF.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("user") 
                    && passwordTF.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("pass")) {

                    // *** Switch to main view: ***

                    Parent mainView = new MainView().getView();
                    view.getScene().setRoot(mainView);

                } else {
                    loginAttempts.set(loginAttempts.get()+1);
                }
            });

            // just set up login UI... irrelevant to this example:


            loginAttempts = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

            usernameTF.setPromptText("Hint: user");
            passwordTF.setPromptText("Hint: pass");

            view.addRow(0, new Label("Username:"), usernameTF);
            view.addRow(1, new Label("Password:"), passwordTF);

            Label loginErrorMessage = new Label();

            loginErrorMessage.textProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(loginAttempts.isEqualTo(0))
                    .then("")
                    .otherwise(Bindings.format("Login incorrect (Attempts: %d)", 
                            loginAttempts)));

            view.add(loginErrorMessage, 0, 2, 2, 1);

            view.add(loginButton, 0, 3, 2, 1);

            ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
            leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
            leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
            ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
            rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            rightCol.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);

            view.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);
            GridPane.setHalignment(loginErrorMessage, HPos.CENTER);
            GridPane.setHalignment(loginButton, HPos.CENTER);

            view.setHgap(10);
            view.setVgap(16);

            view.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }

        public Parent getView() {
            return view ;
        }

    }

    public static class MainView {

        private BorderPane view ;

        public MainView() {

            view = new BorderPane();

            // *** logout button switches back to a login view: ***

            Button logoutButton = new Button("Log out");
            logoutButton.setOnAction(event -> 
                view.getScene().setRoot(new LoginView().getView()));

            // Arbitrary UI, irrelevant to this example:

            SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
            ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .map("Item "::concat)
                .forEach(listView.getItems()::add);

            Label bigLabel = new Label();
            bigLabel.textProperty().bind(
                    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
            bigLabel.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 18));
            BorderPane.setAlignment(bigLabel, Pos.CENTER);
            BorderPane.setMargin(bigLabel, new Insets(10));

            Label details = new Label();
            details.textProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(
                        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull())
                    .then("")
                    .otherwise(Bindings.format("This is where you would display "
                        + "all sorts of details about %1$s. "
                        + "If %1$s were really a model object, you "
                        + "might have a GridPane displaying all its "
                        + "properties, for example.", 
                        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty())));

            details.setWrapText(true);

            BorderPane detailsPane = new BorderPane(details, bigLabel, null, null, null);

            splitPane.getItems().addAll(listView, detailsPane);

            view.setCenter(splitPane);
            view.setBottom(logoutButton);

            BorderPane.setAlignment(logoutButton, Pos.CENTER);
            BorderPane.setMargin(logoutButton, new Insets(8));
            BorderPane.setMargin(splitPane, new Insets(16));
        }

        public Parent getView() {
            return view ;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to change between the contents of a stage ; what I'm doing now is creating a new scene EVERY TIME I'm "changing" between my scenes .

Comment: Surely the answer I posted shows you how to change between the contents of a scene? "How do I switch between scenes, preferably without using FXML?": that's exactly what this code does, no?

Comment: Which means that I have to call .setScene every time I want the screen to change, which causes the screen to resize and flicker for a few seconds.

Comment: It doesn't flicker in my example.

Comment: Can you please focus on scene.setRoot() a little more , because I've seen so many posts about it and none of them seem to have the sufficient amount of information I require to actually understand how to implement it within my own code.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking there? "What does `scene.setRoot(...)` do?" It changes the root element that is displayed in the scene, so it effectively changes the content of the scene.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could implement .setRoot() somewhere in my code ?